# who / w / logname broken in multiple terminals

Tags: linux, terminal, xorg, login, xterm

I have a strange problem: 
In a GUI session, depending on the terminal being used the following two (related) problems appear:

1. `who` and `w` doesn't list the user's active session
2. `logname` returns `logname: no login name`

It happens in the following terminals:

- lxterminal
- xfce4-terminal
- rxvt

On the other hand, in the following scenarios it works perfectly (who/w lists the user and logname functions):

- ssh-ing in
- xterm / lxterm / uxterm

Comment: What are your OS/distro and version, and X server and version?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether lx, xfce, and rxvt are setuid root.  If they are not, but xterm is, try setting them setuid root (`which rxvt|xargs chmod u+s`).  Per [this](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rxvt1.html):

```
rxvt tries to write an entry into the utmp(5) file so that
it can be seen via the who(1) command, and can accept mes­sages.  
To allow this  feature,  rxvt  must  be  installed
setuid root on some systems.
```

"utmp" is `/var/tmp/utmp`, which lists currently logged-on users.  ([This](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-283390-view-next.html?sid=5e67fd4ad047ab9ffe5023e04daa8c57) describes a related problem in which the values in utmp were not properly updated.)

Comment: Excessive privileges alert!  It only needs to be set-GID to the `utmp` group [on Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=500230) and [on LinuxFromScratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.1/chapter06/pwdgroup.html).